# Mapping an array to API call - Error Handling

Tags: javascript

I have an array of addresses:

```
addresses = ['addr1', 'addr2', ... , 'addr_n']
```

which I am mapping to a geocode object like so:

```
geocodedAddresses = addresses.map(addr => this.geocodeAddress(addr))
```

Yielding something like

```
geocodedAddresses = [{lat: xxxx, lng: yyyy}, ... {lat: xxxx, lng:yyyy}]
```

---

Purpose: Show these addresses on a map

So, in case some addresses cannot be geocoded, I still want the rest of addresses to be coded on the map, but somehow inform the user of which addresses that could not be geocoded. What would be a good way of handling this?

I thought of:

1. catching the error in `this.geocodeAddress` and return a *default location*
2. catching the error and returning something like `undefined` and then catch it after mapping. Something like this: `addresses.map(addr => this.geocodeAddress(addr)).filter(geocodedAddress !== 'undefined')`

I am somewhat new to web development and Javascript. Are there any preferences between 1) and 2)? Or is there another, better way?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly opinion based and will probably be closed since such questions are not allowed on Stackoverflow.

My 2 cents are that solution 2 is nice. Plus each time you catch a problem during `geocodeAddress()` you can add it to a list of errors that can be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

First it's important to understand that your approach will only work if the `geocodeAddress` is synchronous. If it's async you have to work with a promise.

But in case that it's synchron, I would recommend that you reduce it into results and errors.

In my case, `geocodeAddress` returns undefined if not successful.

```
const results = addresses.reduce( (acc, address) => {
  const result = geocodeAddress(address);
  if(result) {
    acc.success.push(result);
  } else { 
    acc.errors.push("Error at geocoding: " + address);
  }
  return acc;
}, {success: [], errors: []});
```

This will result in an object with two properties which stores the geocoded addresses and the errors. 
It takes all addresses and for each entry it geocodes it. If the geocoding returns undefined, an error will be added.